# Full rotation of group of object

Tags: mesh

I want to rotate a group of object in its middle, like a clock aram moved with respect to its base.

In pas it was working good, but now its behaving like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Piovt point to "**Median Point**"

[image]